# Doctrine and stored procedure after connection commit

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers, doctrine, connection

I'm trying to call a stored procedure in my project, AFTER an object is saved (like a trigger would do, but MySQL doesn't allow calling stored procedure within a trigger).

First try : I wrote the call in the postInsert() hook, in Doctrine_Record. At this moment, the transaction is not committed to the database, so wrong way.

Second try : I wrote an EventListener and call the postTransactionCommit() event. It works fine, except that I'm not able at this level to know what table was modified. I can know what tables are 'initialized' in this connection, but that's all. And I don't want to call my stored procedure if I'm doing only a SELECT in the transaction.

So now I'm stucked... Do you see a lead I did not follow?

Thanks

Comment: what version of doctrine are you using?

Comment: I'm using Doctrine 1.2.4

Comment: i only use 2.xx, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by overriding the save() method in Doctrine_Record, so the connection is comitted just after the save().